# When should one create new Thread Groups

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadgroup

I was wondering, what are the advantages of assigning threads to a thread group instead of containing them all in one (The Main) group?

Assuming there are 10 or more constantly active threads, and a couple of threads been initiated every now and again as the application requires, how would one approach grouping these?

Thanks,
Adam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no advantage at all. ThreadGroups are there for backward compatibility, but I've never seen them used.

Here's what Brian Goetz (author of *Java Concurrency in Practice* - the bible) [said about them](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-threads/j-threads-pdf.pdf) a long time ago:

> The ThreadGroup class was originally intended to be useful in
>   structuring collectionsof threads into groups. However, it turns out
>   that ThreadGroup is not all that useful. You are better off simply
>   using the equivalent methods in Thread. ThreadGroup does offer one
>   useful feature not (yet) present in Thread: the uncaughtException()
>   method. When a thread within a thread group exits becauseit threw an
>   uncaught exception, the ThreadGroup.uncaughtException() method
>   is called. This gives you an opportunity to shut down the system, write
>   a message to a log file, or restart a failed service.

Threads now have an uncauht exception handler, and this single reason to use thread groups isn't valid anymore.

Comment: Java debuggers aggregate threads according to their `ThreadGroup`, so I think that bookkeeping is one small reason to use them. For example, if one class will start up a few threads for different purposes, it can be nice to put each thread in a common group named for the class, and to give each thread a logical name. I agree that they should not be used for managing execution, though.